# How to call phone plugin in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

Ok I am trying to implement an phone gap plugin, that consists of two parts. I am using cordova 2.0.0 and eclipse.

Here is the java part:

```
package org.apache.cordova;



 import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;

public class Screenshot extends Plugin {

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        // starting on ICS, some WebView methods
        // can only be called on UI threads
        final Plugin that = this;
        final String id = callbackId;
        super.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            //@Override
            public void run() {
                View view = webView.getRootView();

                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                try {
                    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures");
                    if (!folder.exists()) {
                        folder.mkdirs();
                    }

                    File f = new File(folder, "screenshot_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                    that.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK), id);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    that.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.IO_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage()), id);
                }
            }
        });

        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
        result.setKeepCallback(true);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Here is the javascript part:

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/screenshot", function(require, exports, module) {
    var exec = require('cordova/exec');

    /**
     * This class exposes the ability to take a Screenshot to JavaScript
     */
    var Screenshot = function() {};

    /**
     * Save the screenshot to the user's Photo Library
     */
    Screenshot.prototype.saveScreenshot = function() {
        exec(null, null, "Screenshot", "saveScreenshot", []);
    };

    var screenshot = new Screenshot();
    module.exports = screenshot;

});

if (!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.screenshot) {
    window.plugins.screenshot = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/screenshot");
}
```

I am trying to call this with another javascript function on another page, but without success. I hide the anchors of an image on a canvas, then this line:

```
setTimeout(takeScreenShot,500);
```

**EDIT** -- made after Simon MacDonald's answer
this then relates to a javascript function:

```
function takeScreenShot() {
window.plugins.screenshot.saveScreenshot();
}
```

The following java prints:

```
System.out.println(folder);
System.out.println("screenshot_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
```

Produce the following results:

```
/mdt/sdcard/Pictures
screenshot_1347893081276.png
```

**EDIT** After turning the device off and on again, the screenshots I took appeared, the phone seems to cache them, and not actually store them to the selected folder.

I have ensured that my config.xml and my android manifest have the right permissions and lines of code. Anyone see where im going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nowhere in your code do you ever call the saveScreenshot method. Your takeScreenShot method should look like this:

```
function takeScreenShot() {
    window.plugins.screenshot.saveScreenshot();
}
```

Then the screen shot should be saved in "/sdcard/Pictures". This will work if:

1. You remembered to put a plugin line into your config.xml for the screen shot plugin
2. You mentioned this is on another page so make sure that page has a script tag for screenshot.js.

Comment: I implemented that, and added a couple of log messages to the screenshot.java, and it outputs exactly what you say. System.out.println(folder); = /mnt/sdcard/Pictures and System.out.println("screenshot_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"); = screenshot_1347892058037.png. I receive no errors, however it does not actually save the image to that or any directory. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you app has the permission to write to external storage

Comment: I solved this by turning it into a base64, as I didnt want to save it to the phone anyway. However there did seem to be an issue with the phone caching the images and not storing them to the gallery. I did have the write to external storage permission.

Comment: You'd have to modify the Java code to tell it to add those files to the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the Obsolute Path?

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File folder = new File (sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "Pictures");
```

Comment: this sends it to /mnt/sdcardpictures, which doesn't seem quite correct, but either way it doesn't actually save it to the phone. :/ thank you though for the suggestion :)